# PHP Scraping Javascript var

Tags: javascript, php, goutte

how can I **scrape** Javascript var with PHP (Laravel). I'm using Goutte to **scrape** data but I can't fetch this javascript.
This is the code example how is my function written to get Title from aliexpress.

```
$title='';
$crawler->filter('.product-name')->each(
            function ($node)  use (&$title) {
            $title = $node->text();
            });

        return $title;
```

I'm want to catch something like this.

````
var skuProducts=[{"skuId":59123908876,"skuPropIds":"","skuVal":{"availQuantity":3930,"inventory":3930,"isActivity":false,"optionalWarrantyPrice":[],"skuAmount":{"currency":"USD","formatedAmount":"US $19.50","value":19.5},"skuCalPrice":"19.50","skuMultiCurrencyCalPrice":"19.5","skuMultiCurrencyDisplayPrice":"19.50"}}];
            var GaData = {
        pageType: "product",
        productIds: "en2041514744",
        totalValue: "US $19.5"
    };
```PP
````

Comment: `script`.  I never used this but most likely the selectors only work on HTML, that's what they are after all.  So you will have to get the contents of the tag the JS is in, typically a script tag, then write something to parse that content manually.   Not really a pleasant thought, but I don't see how you would select JavaScript with CSS selectors, it's just something they don't do.  There may be other ways, but I never used this as I mentioned.  But logically it makes no sense to Select JS using CSS selectors.

Comment: This example is catching what I need, I want to understand how to write it to catch JavaScript var.

Comment: Obviously,  What I mean is this `$crawler->filter('script')->` the rest is up to you.  You can't select a JS var with a CSS selector.  As I said, and as I also said maybe there is another way, but not by using a CSS selector.  Think about it, what are you going to use for the selector `var` which it would see as `<var>`?   CSS+HTML and JS are 2 different beasts.